# Get java.lang.IllegalAccessError when accessing the private field of a outside class via ASM Java Bytecode

Tags: java, reflection, assembly, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

in reflection, the private field can be access via getDeclaredField() and setAccessible(true). How to access the private field of a outside class via Objectweb ASM bytecode API?
I set to get the private field from something like, via

```
Field current = sourceObject.getDeclaredField(privateFieldName);
Field.setAccessible(true);
Type sourceType = Type.getType(sourceObject.getClass());
mv.visitFieldInsn(Opcodes.GETFIELD,
                  sourceType.getInternalName(),
                  privateFieldname,
                  Type.getDescriptor(current.getType()));
```

When the byte code is executed and to get the private field, I always got an error "java.lang.IllegalAccessError "

Any clue? Thanks a bundle,

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it like that. The `setAccessible(true)` will only affect the current field-reference in the current execution of your program (that is, **it will not affect the execution of the resulting modified program**).

To access a private field when running your modified program, you basically have to embed the corresponding reflection-steps into the program.

To access a private field `YourClass.thePrivatefield` of some object stored in local variable `varId` you do something like

```
// Get hold of the field-reference
mv.visitLdcInsn(Type.getType("LYourClass;"));
mv.visitLdcInsn("thePrivateField");
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL,
                   "java/lang/Class",
                   "getDeclaredField",
                   "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/reflect/Field;");

// Duplicate the reference
mv.visitInsn(DUP);

// Call setAccessible(true) using the first reference.
mv.visitInsn(ICONST_1);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL,
                   "java/lang/reflect/Field",
                   "setAccessible",
                   "(Z)V");

// Call get(yourObject) using the second reference to the field.
mv.visitInsn(ALOAD, varId);
mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKEVIRTUAL,
                   "java/lang/reflect/Field",
                   "get",
                   "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
```

---

If the field you're trying to make accessible is part of the cobe base that your'e rewriting, you could obviously also make that field public by using `ACC_PUBLIC` instead of `ACC_PRIVATE`.

Comment: Great. I will try it. By the way, is this Java ASM or BCEL? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is that you cannot legally access those variables.  This is because the JVM defined its access rules before Java had inner classes, so javac creates synthetic accessors for fields that it cannot legally access in the JVM but can in Java.  For example,

```
class Sample {
    private int i = 0;
    class Inner {
        int foo = i;
    }
}
```

Then we can use `javap` to decompile the generated classes.

```
fowles@morbo:/tmp$ javap -private Sample
Compiled from "Sample.java"
class Sample extends java.lang.Object{
    private int i;
    Sample();
    static int access$000(Sample);
}

fowles@morbo:/tmp$ javap -c Sample.Inner
Compiled from "Sample.java"
class Sample$Inner extends java.lang.Object{
int foo;

final Sample this$0;

Sample$Inner(Sample);
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   aload_1
   2:   putfield    #1; //Field this$0:LSample;
   5:   aload_0
   6:   invokespecial   #2; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   9:   aload_0
   10:  aload_0
   11:  getfield    #1; //Field this$0:LSample;
   14:  invokestatic    #3; //Method Sample.access$000:(LSample;)I
   17:  putfield    #4; //Field foo:I
   20:  return

}
```

Notice the `access$000(Sample)` method that got generated in `Sample` and used from `Sample.Inner`.  Sadly, your options are to either

1. Make the field accessible
2. Use reflection
3. Generate synthetic accessors